# New line on alert message

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Is there anyway to display new lines using an Alert in Ionic 3?

What should I replace '\n' with?

```
doFinalise() {
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  message: 'Are these details correct?\n Price ($/L): \n KMs Done: \n Total Spent: \n Fuel Type: \n Date: ',
  buttons: [ etc...
```

Eventually, the message will display variable just before the new line, but it is not required at this stage.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, how to get this working in Ionic 7: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129651/html-tags-are-not-working-in-ionic-5-alert-text)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AlertController can parse HTML tags. So you can use `<br/>` tag here.

```
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: `Are you sure?`,
  message: `Are these details correct?<br/> Price ($/L): <br/> KMs Done: <br\> Total Spent: <br\> Fuel Type: <br\> Date: `,
  buttons: [ etc...
```

Or you can check [my demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mfn8id?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) and try something with bullets or numbering.

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      message: `
        Are these details correct?
        <ul>
          <li>Price ($/L):</li>
          <li> KMs Done: </li>
          <li>Total Spent: </li>
          <li>Fuel Type:</li>
          <li> Date: </li>
        </ul>
      `,
```

Source: [this forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/alertcontroller-with-line-breaks-and-bullet-points-in-it-is-it-possible/61972/2) by **Mike Hartington** of Ionic

Comment: Working great :-D

Comment: I discovered that If you have white-space: normal; // causes text wrapping in your SCSS, then  \n will be ignored.  I don't have to replace them with <br> :)

Comment: @Meryan yes... as it supports html tags, all of html5 and CSS 3 will work in alert content...

Comment: @SurajRao Sadly your answer is not working anymore in Ionic 7

Comment: @Henning have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75971373/4826457)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have newline character in ionic popup content.

Replace \n with **< br >** tag and it works. The ionic framework outputs HTML after execution of that javascript.

Comment: I discovered that If you have white-space: normal; // causes text wrapping in your SCSS, then  \n will be ignored.  I don't have to replace them with <br> :)