# how to add list in alert box ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

this is the list

```
export class Abc{
    list:string[];

    constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController,public navCtrl: 
          NavController,public navParams:NavParams) 
    {
        this.list=this.navParams.get('list');
    }
```

this is my function in which I want to show the list in alert box.Not only the item names but there thumbnail and price also.

```
backtocart(){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: 'Low battery',
       subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
       buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
} 
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? you are not receiving the list array/object?

Comment: no I am receiving it but I don't know how to use it in alert box and show the data in alert  box

Comment: I think you have to use ModalController instead and use its `cssClass` property to make it look like alert.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913575/4826457

Comment: but my list is dyanamic @SurajRao

Comment: ok.. so maybe use a Modal instead. Alert is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add list to alert box in following way,

```
export class Abc{
  listItems: Array<any> = [];

  backtocart(){    
    this.listItems = [];

    for (let item of this.list) {
      let li = new ListItem;
      li.name = item.name;
      li.thumbnail = item.thumbnail;
      li.price = item.price;
      this.listItems.push(li);
    }

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Low battery',
      subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
      buttons: this.listItems
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}


class ListItem {
  name: string;
  thumbnail: any;
  price: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use a modal, you can make it look like an alert with css.For example:

```
        var z: any = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-modal");
        z[0].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
        z[0].style.padding = "36px";
        z[0].style.paddingTop = "150px";
        z[0].style.paddingBottom = "226px";
        z[0].childNodes[1].style.borderRadius = "6px";
```