# HTML tags are not working in Ionic 5 Alert text

Tags: html, ionic-framework, alert, ionic5

I have migrated the following code from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5

```
   const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      subHeader: "About" + " <b>" + this.user.name + "</b>",
      message: "Test Messgae",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Close',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
```

In Ionic 3 the user name is displayed in Bold font but in Ionic 5 the HTML tags are not working and < b > tags are displayed as text. 
Please suggest how can I style text in alert in IONIC 5.

Comment: I have also noticed this issue recently updating to Ionic 7. Did you find any way to embed HTML elements in the message or subheader? I found it really useful for embedding images in the alert as well as custom CSS for separate parts within the message.

Answer (score 9):

### A word of caution

The html tags appear since Ionic sanitizes the passed string to avoid unsafe html injections. Unsafe html can be used by an attacker to coordinate XSS attacks.

### Solutions

In case you need a simple customization of the html I'd greatly prefer [Tomislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129651/html-tags-are-not-working-in-ionic-5-alert-text/61130342#61130342) to avoid any security risks.

If you need a bit of simple html inside the alert box you can use `message: new IonicSafeString("foo<br>bar")`. If you choose this option be sure to sanitize the html by yourself to make sure the string you pass is safe (see more on [Bypassing the sanitizer on a case-by-case basis](https://ionicframework.com/docs/techniques/security#bypassing-the-sanitizer-on-a-case-by-case-basis)).

If you need to display real html you probably better of using a modal instead of an alert. Alerts are intended to display simple content.

### Updates

Starting on Ionic 7 you need to enable `innerHTMLTemplatesEnabled: true` on your config for `IonicSafeString` to work. See the [breaking changes bug report](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/27118#issuecomment-1497470528).

Comment: Thanks, the setting of property in IonicModule.forRoot method was the tricky part. It helped!

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me because I am using IONIC 7.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot({ innerHTMLTemplatesEnabled: true }),
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule
],
```

Enabling the inner HTML templates. Might be needed because your HTML is being rendered as plain string/text. With this enabled all HTML tags I used was rendered correctly

Hope this helps

Comment: This has solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

`subHeader` can be bold using a custom CSS class. In this example that is `alertCustomClass`.

[image]

**home.page.ts**

```
 async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'About ' + this.test,
      subHeader: this.test,
      message: 'About ' + '<strong>' + this.test + '</strong>',
      cssClass: 'alertCustomClass',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

**global.scss**

```
.alertCustomClass {
      .alert-sub-title {
          font-weight: bold;
      }
 }
```

---

Also, you can bold `message` using `<strong>` [like this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert):

```
  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Confirm!',
      message: 'About ' + '<strong>' + this.user.name + '</strong>',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

`header` will be bold (`font-weight:500;`) as default.

```
...
   header: 'About ' + this.user.name,
   message: ...,
   buttons: ,,,.
...
```

Comment: Workes for message but not for subHeader.

Comment: @TapasMukherjee Can you use `header`  instead of `subHeader`?

Comment: @TapasMukherjee I've added an additional example for styling `subHeader`.

Comment: thanks for putting the effort. I am aware of the custom CSS class. The problem is, it will make the entire text bold. I am not sure why this is changed in Ionic 5